# ListView: Implement MediaPlayer For List Items (non-music)

Tags: android, listview, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am working on a note taking app from a tutorial series on YouTube, since I am very new to Android programming.  The series itself doesn't cover adding in audio, but I am wanting to make it so whenever I click on a note (viewgroup) then I want a sound to play.  I have the sound in my raw folder (R.raw.menu_ok).  However I'm honestly not sure how to implement a basic media player that would just play one sound whenever an item in my list view is pressed.  I've inserted a media player into onListItemClick(), but I don't know how to get the context required in order to not get a "cannot resolve create method" error.  If there is significantly more to this issue than just implementing a media player, could I get links for where I should begin reading on this topic?  If there is too much that needs to be added to make this work, I'll delete the topic to prevent search clutter.

Also I would have just gone with one of the answers from other questions, but they seem to be about how to make audio that is listed in the list view itself play.  I just need a single sound to play across multiple list view items when they are pressed.  The aim of the app itself is to inflate a note view when any of the views in the initial list are pressed, but I want a sound to play when any of the views in the initial list are pressed.

```
package anubitek.missionlog;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

// ================================================
//  MainActivityListFragment:
// ================================================
public class MainActivityListFragment extends ListFragment
{
    private ArrayList<Note> notes;
    private NoteAdapter noteAdapter;

    @Override
    // Tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate().
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        /*String[] values = new String[]{ "Unreal", "Doom", "Quake", "Descent "};

        // getActivity(): The Array Adapter's usage context.
        // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1: Which layout file has a text file view.
        // Values: The array being used in this context.
        // setListAdapter(adapter): Tells list fragment (in this context) to use this adapter to display the list of items.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

        setListAdapter(adapter);*/

        // Create array of notes
        notes = new ArrayList<Note>();

        // Add a new note to "notes", or ArrayList<Note> to first position
        notes.add(new Note("New Note", "Note Body", Note.Category.NOTE));

        // Set up the array adapter
        noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter(getActivity(), notes);

        // Provide the cursor for the list view.
        setListAdapter(noteAdapter);

        getListView().setDivider(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), android.R.color.black));
        getListView().setDividerHeight(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(.this, R.raw.menu_ok);
        mPlayer.start();

        launchNoteDetailActivity(position);
    }

    // When you click on a list item, you want to grab all information for the position
    //  so we can pass it to our note detail activity.
    private void launchNoteDetailActivity(int position)
    {
        // Grab note information associated with whatever note item we clicked on
        Note note = (Note) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        // Create a new intent that launches our noteDetailActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteDetailActivity.class);

        // Pass along the information of the note we clicked on to our noteDetailActivity
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_ID_EXTRA, note.getId());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_TITLE_EXTRA, note.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_MESSAGE_EXTRA, note.getMessage());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_CATEGORY_EXTRA, note.getCategory());

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so this got the sound to play:
`MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.menu_ok);`
But I am seeing something about "prepare()" on other topics.  What would "prepare()" be used for?

Comment: Prepare need to be used when you want to [fetch or decode media data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). As your sound is raw format and in your app you don't need to call prepare.

Answer (score 0):

To get the context for activity, use this instead

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.raw.menu_ok);
```

The `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` is the application context and will remain till the whole application life-cycle is not finished. This may cause memory leak problems.

Also,

1. Declare global MediaPlayer object

   ```
   private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
   ```
2. Instantiate the `MediaPlayer` object in `onCreate` or `onCreateView` followed by a prepare call.

   @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ```
         ...
         mPlayer = ... // init 
         mPlayer.prepare();
         ....

   }
   ```
3. followed by playing in the `onListItemClick`

   ```
   mPlayer.seekTo(0);    
   mPlayer.play();
   ```
4. and finally clean up in `onPause`

   ```
   mPlayer.release();
   ```

This way, you wont be adding a lot of overhead in creating a new MediaPlayer object everytime the user clicks on a list item. Your code is good and will work, but you can make it more efficient in this way. It may look like a lot to do, but trust me, it is worth the effort and can prevent a lot of issues later. speaking from experience :P

EDIT: corrected an error in step 3

Comment: (http://pastebin.com/z0ELgXSp) So here is my updated code with your suggestions added in.  But now I have the problem of trying to access mPlayer across multiple methods.  How do I go about accessing mPlayer in these other methods?  By this I mean I have created a MediaPlayer through onCreate, but I can't access it through onPause as it simple returns "cannot resolve symbol".

Comment: @LannFyre declare `MediaPLayer` as a global variable. Check edited post. Also, there is a small error in the above code, please change step 3 line 1 from `mPlayer.reset()` to `mPlayer.seekTo(0)`